# Custom simplification rules in Sympy in a pseudo-ring

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math, algebra

I am using Sympy to represent elements of a custom commutative pseudo-ring. I would like to make Sympy aware of some specific simplification rules from my domain like

```
x*x = x
n*x = x
```

With these rules, I am expecting something like `x*y*x + y*x` to be simplified in `x*y`. Is there a way to do this in Sympy ? Do you recommend other libs to do that ? (I am only using `expand`, `simplify`, equality testing, `subs` and `parse_expr`)

Comment: How do those rules result in that simplification?

Comment: It goes like this (as I said, `*` is commutative in my domain)
1) `x*y*x = y*x`
2) `y*x+y*x = 2*(y*x) = y*x = x*y`

Answer (score 1):

After several experiments, my best guess is to use custom replacements of the constants based on their extended path (see [Sympy doc on Epath](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/simplify/simplify.html#module-sympy.simplify.epathtools))

```
formula = expand(simplify(EPath("/*/*/Integer").apply(formula, lambda x: Integer(1))))
formula = expand(simplify(EPath("/*/Integer").apply(formula, lambda x: Integer(1))))
formula = expand(simplify(EPath("/Integer").apply(formula, lambda x: Integer(1))))
```

These three lines basically do the required simplification (e.g. `x*y*x + y*x` -> `x*y`).

There might be more elegant solutions but I post this answer since it can help other people.

Answer (score 1):

One solution for this is the following:

```
expr = x*y*x + x*y
expr = expr.subs(x*x, x) # to apply the restriction x*x = x
expr = expr.subs([(n*x, x) for n in expr.args if n%1==0]) #  n*x = x for all n in Z
```

Here,

- `expr.subs(x*x, x)` method substitutes $x^2$ by $x$.
- `expr.args` attribute gives the list of all variables of `expr`.
- `n%1==0` condition gurentees that &n& is integer.